# What is the difference between lstm(256) + lstm(256) and lstm(512)?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm

here is code

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(None, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(None, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

this is lstm(256) + lstm(256) code

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(512, input_shape=(None, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

this is lstm(512) code

So, What is the difference between lstm(256) + lstm(256) and lstm(512)?

Is it just parallel, and in the end, it means the same thing?

Or what is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 1):

The 2 architectures you are presenting are not the same.

The first model has 2 LSTM layers, which are stacked on top of each other. The first LSTM layer takes a single input parameter and outputs 256 parameters, the second LSTM layer has 256 input parameters and it returns the same number as parameters as its output, so the input to the final layer has a width of 256 parameters.

The second model has a single LSTM layer that takes a single input parameter and outputs 512 parameters, which act as the input to the final layer (and not 256 as in the first model).

Stacking LSTM layers makes the model deeper, and potentially allows the hidden state at each level to operate at different timescales.

If you want to learn more about stacking LSTM layers, you will find the following link to a post by Jason Brownlee very informative:

[Stacked Long Short-Term Memory Networks](https://machinelearningmastery.com/stacked-long-short-term-memory-networks/)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not just parallel in first case each cell of first layer interacts wis appropriate cell of second layer. And in second case it is just one layer of LSTM with works in usual manner. I hope the image helps you to see the difference.

[image: two layer LSTM]